# Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I use this code to connect to the SharePoint online environment:

```
$username = "xxxxxxxx" 
$password = "xxxxxxxx"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredentials ($username, $password)
connect-pnponline -url xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -Credential $credential
```

But I get the error: The remote server returned an error (403) Forbidden

How can I solve this?

Gr, P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PSCredential` needs a `SecureString` rather than a plain `string`.

```
$encpassword = convertto-securestring -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $encpassword

connect-pnponline -url xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -Credential $credential
```

Comment: Still receive the message: "the remote server returned an error (403) forbidden

Comment: Got it :) the url wasn't correct. Thanks for the help.